# Function notation for arguments

Tags: functions, notation

Say you have a function f and it has one argument x so you can write f(x). It seems in math that you can replace x with x+1 so you get f(x+1). It's ordered pair would then be (x+1,f(x+1)) and not (x,f(x)), right? So in this case x+1 took on x's role. But at the same time you are still wanting to refer to the new value x+1 in terms of x to see what happens when you put in x incremented by one into the function.

So is x just a placeholder and not the actual argument for function f in the notation f(x)? Should you think about what's between the parentheses as the argument and not the variable x as the argument?

Comment: " Should you think about what's between the parentheses as the argument and not the variable x as the argument?"  Yes.  If we have f((x+1)), and 'f' is the squaring function, then to find the expanded form we would figure out the square of (x+1).  Thus, "(x+1)" is argument, we should think about what's between the parentheses for the function symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get into the habit of denoting a function by just the letter $f$ (or whatever else it is called) instead of $f(x)$ to avoid this kind of confusion.

A function $f : A \to B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets, is usually defined to be its graph: the set of points $(a, f(a)) \in A \times B$. To be clear, this isn't the definition of what it means to be a function; I just want to point out that a function is represented as a set of ordered pairs.

On the other hand, $f(x)$ is a (probably arbitrary) element of the range of $f$ (assuming $x$ lies in the domain of $f$, i.e. $A$, otherwise the expression $f(x)$ doesn't make sense).

For example, if we define $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by the rule $f(x) = x^3 - x$, then whenever $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then $f(x)$ is a **real number**, not a function. The function $f$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$, specifically
$$f = \{(x, x^3 - x) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \in \Bbb{R}\},$$
which is **not** a real number like $f(x)$.

That said, this is a fairly hardline stance, which I make for pedagogical reasons. We all, from time to time, get sloppy on the above point. I will, for different pedagogical reasons, refer to a function $f$ as $f(x)$ (when I think the fact that $f$ is a function may potentially be lost on my audience). It's wrong, but if I think it helps more than it hinders understanding, I will do it.

It's also common to define a function informally as an expression of $x$, or $t$, or some other pronumeral understood from context to be independent. For example, I could say that the function $x^2 + 2x$ has a minimum of $-1$, and most people would know what I meant. If I wanted to be formal and proper, I could define $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by $x \mapsto x^2 + 2x$, and say that $f$ has a minimum value $-1$.

Now, let's address your question. If you see $f(x + 1)$ (where I assume $f$ is a function with domain $\Bbb{R}$, or something similar), then I would interpret it as the function
$$\{(x, f(x + 1)) : x \in \Bbb{R}\}, \tag{$\star$}$$
not the function
$$\{(x + 1, f(x + 1)) : x \in \Bbb{R}\},$$
which is actually $f$. What they are doing is defining a function informally, like we did with $x^2 - 2x$. What they should be doing, from a very formal standpoint, is talking about the function $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto f(x + 1)$, or perhaps writing $(\star)$ (though few would actually go to the trouble of writing the latter).

Comment: On a side note: So R→R:x↦f(x+1) is the function f but shifted to the left by one. Is it okay to prove it by substituting x with x-1 giving f((x-1)+1) = f(x)? Can you substitute x with x-1? Or should you write u=x and therefore f(u-1)+1)=f(u)?

Comment: It's fine to do either. Replacing a dummy variable $x$ with $x-1$ is perfectly fine to do, though it can cause some people some confusion. If you think it makes your process more clear, making a new dummy variable $u$ is a good way of going about it. But, as I said, from a mathematical standpoint, either is fine.