# Notation of functions that take other functions as arguments

Tags: functions, notation

With the usual function notation, one denotes functions as $f: A \to B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277004/function-notation-for-arguments)), e.g. $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for $f(x) = x^2$.

My question is: What would the notation be if a function $f$ takes another function $g: C \to D$, where $C$ and $D$ are again sets, as its argument?

<s>Would it be $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f: D \to B}$? Or $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{f: C \to B}$? Or something else?</s>

<s>I am leaning towards the second option because set $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}D$ should match set $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}A$ as the output of function $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}g$ is the input to $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}f$. I am not sure whether this is always the case and whether I am missing something, however.</s>

Edit: Matthew Towers is absolutely right, what I was wrongfully thinking of was composition of functions. The question, however, is targeted at a function that takes another function as input and I do not know what the notation would look like in that case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The set of functions from $C$ to $D$ is denoted $C^D$. If you say $f:C^D\to B$, then $f$ has a function $g:C\to D$ as an input, and has an element $b\in B$ as an output.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}f: C^D \rightarrow \text{wherever f goes to} \\ g \mapsto \text{whatever f does} \end{align*}

Example
Let $ \;  g:A \rightarrow B \;,h: B \rightarrow C $
\begin{align*} \phi_h: A^B \rightarrow A^C \\ g\mapsto h \circ g  \end{align*}